# Method not allow using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning AJAX with jQuery but I run into this problem where my page says that `jquery-3.6.0.js:10109 POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/data/addToCart.json 405 (Method Not Allowed)`. My page has the `Add to cart` button and I want to print the price that I set in `json` file but it comes to the 405 error. This is the first time I see this problem, I don't really know how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
function addItem(id,name, description, price, moreInfo) {
        $('#input-new-item').val('')
        let html = '';
        html+='<div class="item" data-id="'+id+'">'
        html+='<div class="name">'+name+'</div>'
        html+='<img src="assets/python.png" alt="picture">'
        html+='<div class="description">'+description+'</div>'
        html+='<div class="price">'+price+'</div>'
        html += '<button class="item-add">Add to cart</button>'
        html += '<button class="item-remove">Remove</button>'
        html+='<a class="more-info-link" href="#">More info</a>'
        html+='<div class="more-info">'+moreInfo+'</div>'
        html += '</div>'
        
        $('#container').prepend(html);   
}
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax('data/item.json', {
                type: "get",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                cache: false
        })
                .done(function (response) {
                        let items = response.items
                        items.forEach(item => {
         
                                addItem(item.id,item.name, item.description, item.price, item.moreInfo)
                        });
                })
                .fail(function (request, errorType, errorMessage) {
                      
                })
        
        $('#container').on('click', '.item-add', function () {
                let id = $(this).parent().data('id')
                $.ajax('data/addToCart.json', {
                        type: "post",
                        data:{id: id },
                        dataType:'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json'
                })
                        .done(function (response) {
                                if (response.message == 'Successfully added') {
                                        console.log(response.price)
                                }
                        })
                        
        })
                
        
});
```

Comment: `addToCart.json` not support post method. it is json file.

Comment: @Vel, I watch the tutorial and it works just fine but mine does not :(((

Comment: you want to add item to json file? Also which language you are using PHP or?

Comment: @Vel, so basically I am doing exactly as what the tutorial is doing, they use post method and then they print whatever is in that json file.

Comment: @Vel, it's a course on Udemy, kinda hard to reference it, I have told you exactly what the video does

Comment: check this line `$.ajax('data/addToCart.json', {` in tutorial. They will use something different. share me the tutorial url.

Comment: https://www.udemy.com/share/1029SyAEYZd1hWQnUJ/
Go to lesson 26 and it is around 7th minute.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14XMafnH1i04zj__5RDnhDgw9VkwRUy39/view?usp=sharing
This is the picture of that scene

Comment: I can send you those files via email or what way you prefer?

Comment: I use javascript and its library jQuery only. By the way, when you remove the `type:"post"`, is it gonna be `get` because as far as I know `get` is the default type

Comment: what is the use `get` and `post` methods in your code?. no use. Its just return the json.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for helping today, I really appreciate it

Comment: Are you running the code in nginx or apache?

Comment: @Vel, I am running it by local host

Comment: Add your local path in Ajax url

Comment: @Vel, I put the url with my local path but it does not work whenever I put `type: "post"` in the ajax, I think what you said is right, json file is not supported to work with `post` method